Matching text using more than one column in excel 2016
I'm trying to use MATCH with INDEX to retrieve a value from a different sheet based on 2 columns. Basically from Sheet1 I need to bring the Value located on Sheet2 using Project1 and Project2, when both match, I should show the Value, otherwise empty.
In my case I'm not doing sum of numbers, I just need to get text based on looking for data in separated columns
I was using this without luck:
This formula is on Sheet1 C3 and C4:
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C, MATCH([@Project1] & [@Project2], Sheet2!A:A & Sheet!B:B,0))


There are various approaches depending on whether the values are numeric or not, as well as your version of Excel, all covered in the linked thread.

The linked thread does cover Excel 2016 with looking for strings? I cannot find it

Section 2b). Using AGGREGATE.
